# Use plpgsql to count records selected for output AND output those records

Tags: postgresql, select, count

My query SELECTs 1 row from table1, which has a number of fields plus one very long text field. It JOINs with a second table2, that may have many matching corresponding rows.
I would like to be able to spread the long text field, from table1, out over multiple lines (the number determined by the matching rows in table2).

[image]

In the table above there is one row from Table1 where the key is table1_key = 'DU' and year = '2017'.  Then there are four rows from Table2 with matching keys that include the programme_code and course_code. The field long_text_field, which I want to spread over multiple lines, comes from Table1.

Is it possible to extract a total row count for records that have been selected for output and still output the rows?  Meaning that I want to see a count of 4 from the above and be able to work with this number in the displayed output.  So that the result looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question with sample input and output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your example, but if that's just an illustration of the question in the heading, the answer is a window function:

```
SELECT /* all your columns and expressions */,
       count(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM /* the rest of your query */
```

This will append a column to each result row with the total number of result rows.

The window function is called after `GROUP BY`, but before `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Comment: Thanks for this Laurenz - sorry about the delay in responding.  Window Functions - they look like they can solve this problem and some others that I am facing now.  Thanks again.